# Add "Remove" buttons dynamically to an HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As simple as it is, the idea of my question is that I have an array of JSON objects, I want to dynamically append these objects to an HTML table, and in the last `td` I want to add a remove button so I can remove the row.

Actually I've spend several days looking for an efficient solution but unfortunately didn't find anything.

I've tried to do it in my own and this is what I came up with:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
  var tr = "<tr>";
  var td1 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["empID"] + "</td>";
  var td2 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["fname"] + "</td>";
  var td3 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["lname"] + "</td>";
  var td4 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
  var td5 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["address"] + "</td>";
  var td6 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["deptID"] + "</td>";
  var td7 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["email"] + "</td>";
  var td8 = "<td>" + '<button id="' + objArr[i]["empID"] + '" value="' + objArr[i]["empID"] + '" onclick="onClickDelete(' + objArr[i]["empID"] + ')">Delete</button>' + "</td></tr>";

  $("#dataTable").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5 + td6 + td7 + td8);

}
```

But as you may notice, this is not the efficient manner to accomplish that.
I'm pretty sure that definitely there is a better solution for this.

So could anyone please provide any suggestions

Comment: actually no I'm not using it @AneeshSivaraman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to pass the `event` to the function `onClickDelete` so you can get the button with [`event.target`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp). Then, you can get the parent `tr` using [`parents('tr')`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/). Finally, remove it using [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function.

I don't know your `objArr` so I made it.

```js
var objArr = [
  {
    empID:'empID1',
    fname: 'fname1',
    lname: 'lname1',
    phone: 'phone1',
    address: 'address1',
    deptID: 'deptID1',
    email: 'email1'
  },
  {
    empID:'empID2',
    fname: 'fname2',
    lname: 'lname2',
    phone: 'phone2',
    address: 'address2',
    deptID: 'deptID2',
    email: 'email2'
  }
];

for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
  var tr = "<tr>";
  var td1 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["empID"] + "</td>";
  var td2 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["fname"] + "</td>";
  var td3 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["lname"] + "</td>";
  var td4 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
  var td5 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["address"] + "</td>";
  var td6 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["deptID"] + "</td>";
  var td7 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["email"] + "</td>";
  var td8 = "<td>" + '<button id="' + objArr[i]["empID"] + '" value="' + objArr[i]["empID"] + '" onclick="onClickDelete(event, ' + objArr[i]["empID"] + ')">Delete</button>' + "</td></tr>";

  $("#dataTable").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + td5 + td6 + td7 + td8);
}

function onClickDelete(event) {
  $(event.target).parents('tr').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable"></table>
```

Also, let my suggest you a better approach (on my opinion) for all your code.

```js
var objArr = [
  {
    empID:'empID1',
    fname: 'fname1',
    lname: 'lname1',
    phone: 'phone1',
    address: 'address1',
    deptID: 'deptID1',
    email: 'email1'
  },
  {
    empID:'empID2',
    fname: 'fname2',
    lname: 'lname2',
    phone: 'phone2',
    address: 'address2',
    deptID: 'deptID2',
    email: 'email2'
  }
];

var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
  html = "<tr>";
  html += "<td>" + objArr[i]["empID"] + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + objArr[i]["fname"] + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + objArr[i]["lname"] + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + objArr[i]["phone"] + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + objArr[i]["address"] + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + objArr[i]["deptID"] + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + objArr[i]["email"] + "</td>";
  html += "<td>" + '<button>Delete</button>' + "</td></tr>";

  $("#dataTable").append(html);
}

$('#dataTable').on('click', 'button', onClickDelete);

function onClickDelete() {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable"></table>
```

That's way, your code will be cleaner and easy to read.

Comment: Dear, thanks for your answer, but actually it doesn't solve my issue.
I'm not asking about handling the deletion process, I've already done that in the OnClickDelete method in which I'm deleting the row not from the table only, but even it deletes it from the database.

What I'm looking for is just a better way rather than this in which I can -efficiently- attach a "Remove" button to each row. Event handling is another story

Comment: Sorry I've just seen you edit, nice, this almost what I'm looking for. Thanks again dear

Comment: My pleasure.. `this almost` what else?

Comment: Actually your solution solves my issue so I get rid of repeated vars, but have a look please at the solutions below in which the code is shrunk more which was exactly what I needed. But again, what you have provided almost solves my issue.

Comment: I didn't thoughts that you want/can use a plugin (such as underscore). If you do, I recommend on AngularJS. It will make your life much easier not just with the templates engine, but also with logic of the delete (and insert etc.)

Comment: As I mentioned before, I'm very new to jQuery. So I'm greatly appreciate all of your answers which always bring additional knowledge for me. I will have a look at AngularJS as you suggested. Thanks a lot dear for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution use [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) to create your DOM (jQuery it is not necessary).

The template is created using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (ES 6).

DocumentFragments is faster than repeated single DOM node injection and allows to perform DOM node operations (like adding events) on new elements instead of mass-injection via innerHTML. DocumentFragment is a good solution when performing lots of DOM operations which could speed up time if you table is a big one.

```js
var data = [{
  empID: 'empID1',
  fname: 'fname1',
  lname: 'lname1',
  phone: 'phone1',
  address: 'address1',
  deptID: 'deptID1',
  email: 'email1'
}, {
  empID: 'empID2',
  fname: 'fname2',
  lname: 'lname2',
  phone: 'phone2',
  address: 'address2',
  deptID: 'deptID2',
  email: 'email2'
}];
var temp = document.createElement('table');
var html = '';
html += '<table style="width:100%">';
data.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
  html += `<tr>`;
  html += `<th>${item.empID}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.fname}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.lname}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.phone}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.address}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.deptID}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.email}</th>`;
    html += `<th><button type="button">Remove</button></th>`;
  html += `</tr>`;
});
  html += `</tr>`;
html += '</table>';
temp.innerHTML = html;
document.getElementById('output').appendChild(temp);
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

The following script instead use string concatenation.

Both solutions append data from a JavaScript object to an HTML table and add a button at the end of each row as for your requirement.

```js
var data = [{
  empID: 'empID1',
  fname: 'fname1',
  lname: 'lname1',
  phone: 'phone1',
  address: 'address1',
  deptID: 'deptID1',
  email: 'email1'
}, {
  empID: 'empID2',
  fname: 'fname2',
  lname: 'lname2',
  phone: 'phone2',
  address: 'address2',
  deptID: 'deptID2',
  email: 'email2'
}];
var html = '';
html += '<table style="width:100%">';
data.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
  html += `<tr>`;
  html += `<th>${item.empID}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.fname}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.lname}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.phone}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.address}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.deptID}</th>`;
  html += `<th>${item.email}</th>`;
    html += `<th><button type="button">Remove</button></th>`;
  html += `</tr>`;
});
  html += `</tr>`;
html += '</table>';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use template, such as underscore.js, mustache or handlebars. This is an example with underscore.

1. On your HTML add a script tag of type='text/template' and with an id(#row) like this:

   ```
   <tr>
       <td><%= name %></td>
       <td><%= lastName %></td>
   </tr>
   ```

2.Then on javascript:

```
var obj = [{name:"Diego",lastName:"Gallegos"}, {name:"Juan",lastName:"Perez"}];

for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
     /* Pass the html of the template on step 1 to the _.template function 
        from underscore (_). Import it from its cdn */
     var row = _.template( $('#row').html() ); 

     /*  Then to the tbody of the of your table then only append each row    
         passing the object from the array. row is now a function that          
         receives an object and compiles the template to html */
     $('tbody').append(row(obj[i])); 
}
```

This is way better than using strings.

Answer (score 0):

You might like [my solution](https://jsfiddle.net/u32vgjeb/1/) as well. I am using ES6 template strings, thereby the code is a little bit more readable and concise.

```
var rowsHtml = data.map(function(row) {
  var cellsHtml, row, removeButton = $('<button>', {
    text: 'Remove'
  });

  for (var i in row) if (row.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      cellsHtml += `<td>${row[i]}</td>`;
  }

  row = $(`<tr>${cellsHtml}</tr>`);
  removeButton.click(function() {
    row.remove();
  });

  return row.append(removeButton);
});

$table.append(rowsHtml);
```

**Explanation**

Basically I am doing a for loop over your data, but I use a map function instead, cause it returns new array right away.

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var newNumbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    newNumbers.push(numbers[i] + 1);
}

// newNumbers = [2, 3 ,4]

var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var newNumbers = numbers.map(function(number) {
    return number + 1;
});

// same result, but seems better for my eyes lol - newNumbers = [2, 3 ,4]
```

Then in the first line I create a button that is jQuery object using quite straight forward syntax:

```
$(htmlElement, objectOfProperties);
$('<div>', {
    text: 'SomeDiv',
    "class": 'foobar' // I wrap class in quotes cause it is a reserved keyword
});
// would create <div class="foobar">SomeDiv</div>, but I can call a jQuery methods on it
```

Right now in a `for-in` **loop over single row** I create our table cells. This is what you are doing like this:

```
var td1 = "<td>" + objArr[i]["empID"] + "</td>";
```

At this point `cellsHtml` is just a simple string. As I want to call a jQuery method `append` on it I use same approach as when I was creating a removeButton to make flat HTML a jQuery object.

Now I use jQuery `click` method passing a handler that on click will remove a row that we are currently dealing with.

At the end I append our button (cause I haven't done it yet, our row contains just table cells with data) and return the row, which is added to our result array (behind the scenes by map function).

Comment: Could you please explain more your code, I'm new to jQuery and not sure I'm understanding it well. Thanks anyways

Comment: @AliAlhamaly I have added some explanation. If you have any questions feel free to ask, I will try to explain it in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using JQuery, its best if you dont use onclick method as we have `this` selector in JQuery, you can reduse ur code to the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
  var data = "<tr>";
  data+= "<tr><td>" + objArr[i].empID + "</td><td>" + objArr[i].fname + "</td><td>" + objArr[i].lname + "</td><td>" + objArr[i].phone + "</td>     <td>" + objArr[i].address + "</td><td>" + objArr[i].deptID + "</td><td>" + objArr[i].email + "</td><td><button class='deleteRow' id=" +  objArr[i].empID +">Delete</button> </td></tr>";
  $("#dataTable").append(data);
}
```

then later

```
$(document).delegate(".deleteRow", "click", function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

and i think it will be enough for what u need.

Comment: Nice solution also, but as you might noticed, in my solution I'm passing the `empID` as a value within the `button` element, so I can use it later to perform the deletion process (request a deletion from the database not only delete it from the html table). So, how can I do that using ur code?

Comment: I've just tried to implement your solution, the code doesn't recognize this line of code `objArr[i].length', it says that `length` is undefined

Comment: my bad, thanks for pointing out the issue, now i have made changes and edited the answer, please have a look at it, it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

please use the following code.

**HTML**

```
<table id="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>EmpId</th>
      <th>fname</th>
      <th>lname</th>
      <th>phone</th>
      <th>address</th>
      <th>deptID</th>
      <th>email</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  objArr = [
  { empID : 1, fname: 'Employee1', lname: 'Last name1', phone : '234242344', address: 'address1', deptID : '1', email : 'abc@abc.com'},
  { empID : 2, fname: 'Employee2', lname: 'Last name2', phone : '234244243', address: 'address2', deptID : '1', email : 'cde@cde.com'}
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
    var emp = objArr[i];
    $("#dataTable").append("<tr><td>" + emp.empID + "</td><td>" + emp.fname + "</td><td>" + emp.lname + "</td><td>" + emp.phone + "</td>     <td>" + emp.address + "</td><td>" + emp.deptID + "</td><td>" + emp.email + "</td><td><button class='delete' id=" +  emp.empID +" name=" + emp.fname + ">Delete</button> </td></tr>");
   }

   $(".delete").click(function(){
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + emp.fname + ' ?')) {
         var empId = this.id; //for deletion from server
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      }       
   });

});
```

**CSS**

```
#dataTable td {
  padding : 10px;
}

#dataTable th {
  padding : 10px;
}
```

Refer this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xs9e6moL/57/)